# Tranfer data between canvas with pubnub and webrtc successfully

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, webrtc, pubnub

I am trying to implement a small app (example in order to make my main app to work) where when the user from one canvas clicks a button, the other user's channels numbers changes in order to become the same as the user that clicked the button on the first canvas (this is implemented as it shown below with webrtc and pubnub! ). 
The problem is that data are never exchanged between peers so the channel is never changed. Please help!!

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">

    <title>CoDoodler</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Draw">
    <meta name="author" content="Tomomi Imura  @girlie_mac">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
        <script src="http://cdn.pubnub.com/pubnub.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<script>var canvas_flag = false;</script>
    <header>
        <div>
            <h1>CoDoodler</h1>
            <h2>Doodle with strangers on InterWeb!</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="bubble">
            <span id="occupancy">0</span>
            <span id="unit">doodler</span>
        </div>
    </header>

    <section id="main">
        <canvas id="drawCanvas" width="300" height="300">Canvas is not supported on this browser!</canvas>

        <section id="colorSwatch">
            <input type="radio" name="color" id="color01" data-color="gold" checked><label for="color01"></label> 
            <input type="radio" name="color" id="color02" data-color="darkorange">  <label for="color02"></label>  
            <input type="radio" name="color" id="color03" data-color="navy">        <label for="color03"></label>  
            <input type="radio" name="color" id="color04" data-color="yellowgreen"> <label for="color04"></label>  
            <input type="radio" name="color" id="color05" data-color="firebrick">   <label for="color05"></label>  
            <input type="radio" name="color" id="color06" data-color="powderblue">  <label for="color06"></label> 
        </section>
    </section>

    <footer>
        Powered by <a href="http://pubnub.com" target="_blank">PubNub</a><br>
        Read the tutorial on <a href="http://pubnub.com/blog/multiuser-draw-html5-canvas-tutorial/" target="_blank">PubNub Blog</a>
    </footer>

    <a href="https://github.com/pubnub/codoodler" target="_blank"><img class="github" style="position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0; border: 0;" src="https://camo.githubusercontent.com/365986a132ccd6a44c23a9169022c0b5c890c387/68747470733a2f2f73332e616d617a6f6e6177732e636f6d2f6769746875622f726962626f6e732f666f726b6d655f72696768745f7265645f6161303030302e706e67" alt="Fork me on GitHub" data-canonical-src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/github/ribbons/forkme_right_red_aa0000.png"></a>

    <script>
        // For history() demo, please view history.html.
        var drawHistory = false;

          var number =  Math.floor(Math.random()*999+1); //phone variable

          var string_number = number.toString();

                var pubnub = PUBNUB({
          subscribe_key: 'demo', // always required
          publish_key: 'demo'    // only required if publishing
        });


          function function1(){

                pubnub.publish({
                  channel: 'canvas_channel2000',    
                  'message' : {              
                   'canvas_channel_number':  string_number             
                  },                   
                   callback : function(m){console.log(m)}
            });
        }

        function change_the_canvas_channel_(m){

            string_number = m.canvas_channel_number;
            console.log("tora to kanali egine"+ string_number);


        }

                 pubnub.subscribe({ 
               channel: 'canvas_channel2000',
               message: function(m){change_the_canvas_channel_(m)}
               error: function (error) {
               // Handle error here
                  console.log(JSON.stringify(error));

                }
            });

    </script>
<button type="button" onclick = "function1()">Submit</button>

    <script src="js/test1.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

**test1.js**

```
  (function() {
    /* Canvas */

    var canvas = document.getElementById('drawCanvas');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var color = document.querySelector(':checked').getAttribute('data-color');

    canvas.width =  300;
    canvas.height =  300;

    ctx.strokeStyle = color;
    ctx.lineWidth = '3';
    ctx.lineCap = ctx.lineJoin = 'round';

    /* Mouse and touch events */

    document.getElementById('colorSwatch').addEventListener('click', function() {
        color = document.querySelector(':checked').getAttribute('data-color');
    }, false);

    var isTouchSupported = 'ontouchstart' in window;
    var isPointerSupported = navigator.pointerEnabled;
    var isMSPointerSupported =  navigator.msPointerEnabled;

    var downEvent = isTouchSupported ? 'touchstart' : (isPointerSupported ? 'pointerdown' : (isMSPointerSupported ? 'MSPointerDown' : 'mousedown'));
    var moveEvent = isTouchSupported ? 'touchmove' : (isPointerSupported ? 'pointermove' : (isMSPointerSupported ? 'MSPointerMove' : 'mousemove'));
    var upEvent = isTouchSupported ? 'touchend' : (isPointerSupported ? 'pointerup' : (isMSPointerSupported ? 'MSPointerUp' : 'mouseup'));

    canvas.addEventListener(downEvent, startDraw, false);
    canvas.addEventListener(moveEvent, draw, false);
    canvas.addEventListener(upEvent, endDraw, false);

    /* PubNub */

    var pubnub = PUBNUB.init({
        publish_key     : 'pub-c-465c4b3b-0b7d-40de-86c5-10a9433058b5',
        subscribe_key   : 'sub-c-43a257e0-d94a-11e4-a2b8-0619f8945a4f',
        leave_on_unload : true
    });

    pubnub.subscribe({
        channel: string_number,
        callback: drawFromStream,
        presence: function(m){
            if(m.occupancy > 1){
                document.getElementById('unit').textContent = 'doodlers';
            }
            document.getElementById('occupancy').textContent = m.occupancy;
            var p = document.getElementById('occupancy').parentNode;
            p.classList.add('anim');
            p.addEventListener('transitionend', function(){p.classList.remove('anim');}, false);
        }
    });

    function publish(data) {
        pubnub.publish({
            channel: string_number,
            message: data
        });
     }

    /* Draw on canvas */

    function drawOnCanvas(color, plots) {
        ctx.strokeStyle = color;
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(plots[0].x, plots[0].y);

        for(var i=1; i<plots.length; i++) {
            ctx.lineTo(plots[i].x, plots[i].y);
        }
        ctx.stroke();
    }

    function drawFromStream(message) {
        if(!message || message.plots.length < 1) return;
        drawOnCanvas(message.color, message.plots);
    }

    // Get Older and Past Drawings!
    if(drawHistory) {
        pubnub.history({
            channel  : string_number,
            count    : 50,
            callback : function(messages) {
                pubnub.each( messages[0], drawFromStream );
            }
        });
    }
    var isActive = false;
    var plots = [];

    function draw(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // prevent continuous touch event process e.g. scrolling!
        if(!isActive) return;

        var x = isTouchSupported ? (e.targetTouches[0].pageX - canvas.offsetLeft) : (e.offsetX || e.layerX - canvas.offsetLeft);
        var y = isTouchSupported ? (e.targetTouches[0].pageY - canvas.offsetTop) : (e.offsetY || e.layerY - canvas.offsetTop);

        plots.push({x: (x << 0), y: (y << 0)}); // round numbers for touch screens

        drawOnCanvas(color, plots);
    }

    function startDraw(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        isActive = true;
    }

    function endDraw(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        isActive = false;

        publish({
            color: color,
            plots: plots
        });

        plots = [];
    }
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

I see you are not using the test1.js to publish or subscribe, it's just a canvas code from the PubNub tutorial page, so I ignore the js to test your code.
it would be nice if you can clean up before posting a question!

Anyway, publish and subscribe do work as they should.

I modified your code so you can see when subscription occurs on the 2nd user's browser window-

1. Init:

```
    var pubnub = PUBNUB({
      subscribe_key: 'sub-c-...', 
      publish_key: 'pub-c-...'    
    });
```

Please use your own`subscribe_key` and `publish_key` keys, not the ones you copied from the tutorial! Otherwise, use 'demo' for both.

2. Upon an `onclick` event, your app publish a random number as a string:

```
    pubnub.publish({
      channel: 'canvas_channel2000',    
      'message' : {              
        'canvas_channel_number': string_number             
      },                   
      callback : function(m){console.log(m)}
    });
```

3. Subscribing

```
    pubnub.subscribe({ 
      channel: 'canvas_channel2000',
      message: function(m){
        console.log(m);
      }
    });
```

When the message is successfully subscribed, you should see the object on your browser console.
The code above (removed some of your code that does not make sense, e.g. `uuid` in subscribe) works as expected.

Also, I advise you to use debug console too!
http://www.pubnub.com/console/

Comment: Great!!! and yeah I forgot to mention that you should use the latest pubnub.js too! //cdn.pubnub.com/pubnub-3.7.12.min.js

Comment: My mistake, it is not working properly.. Please recheck it